# How do I create sqlite3 table with a dict of json objects where the keys may not match on every item?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I am currently trying to create a series of tables. The first two tables populate fine as every entry has keys that match what the table was created with.

First table: 1 row containing 3 columns (object, has_more, data)

Second table: handful of rows with 11 columns (object, id, type, updated_at, uri, name, description, size, download_uri, content_type, content_encoding)

Third table: using the same method as previous, I pulled the keys and joined as a string to use in the "CREATE TABLE" statement. This worked for the first couple entries but then next JSON object had different keys which caused an error, "table has 64 columns but 60 values were supplied". I'm assuming this will probably happen with more entries, whether more or less columns/values.

Code follows:

```
import requests
import urllib
import json
import sqlite3
from os import path, replace

BulkDATAurl = "https://api.scryfall.com/bulk-data"      # Store URL path as (str)
BulkDataJSON = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(BulkDATAurl))

#OPEN DATABASE CONNECTION AND SET CURSOR
connection = sqlite3.connect("JSONTestDB")
cursor = connection.cursor()

#CREATE MAIN BULKDATA TABLE - this works but open to other suggestions
columns = ", ".join('"' + str(x) + '"' for x in BulkDataJSON.keys())
values = ", ".join('"' + str(x) + '"' for x in BulkDataJSON.values())
CreateTableCmd = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTable (" + columns + ")"
InsertTableCmd = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);" % ('TestTable', columns, values) 
cursor.execute(CreateTableCmd)
cursor.execute(InsertTableCmd)
connection.commit()

#CREATE BULKDATA DATA TABLE - also works like previous
columns = ", ".join('"' + str(x) + '"' for x in  BulkDataJSON['data'][0].keys())
CreateTableCmd = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTableData (" + columns + ")"
cursor.execute(CreateTableCmd)
i=0
for item in BulkDataJSON['data']:    
    values = ", ".join('"' + str(x) + '"' for x in  BulkDataJSON['data'][i].values())
    i += 1
    InsertTableCmd = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);" % ('TestTableData', columns, values) 
    cursor.execute(InsertTableCmd)
connection.commit()

#CREATE TABLE FROM EXTRACTED URL - this is where my problem happens, 3rd item has less keys, some of which dont even match
oracleURL = BulkDataJSON['data'][2]['download_uri']
oracleJSON = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(oracleURL))
columns = ", ".join('"' + str(x) + '"' for x in oracleJSON[00000].keys())
CreateTableCmd = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTableOracle (" + columns + ")"
cursor.execute(CreateTableCmd)

i=0
for item in oracleJSON[00000]:    
    values =  ", ".join('"' + str(x).replace('"', '-') + '"' for x in  oracleJSON[i].values())
    i += 1
    InsertTableCmd = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);" % ('TestTableOracle', columns, values) 
    cursor.execute(InsertTableCmd)
    connection.commit()

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

From here I'm not entirely sure where to go, or if there's a more efficient way to carry out what I'm trying to do, any help would be greatly appreciate. Also apologies if there are posts that cover this, I may have missed it or misunderstood it.

Comment: (1) You should really use parametrized queries; as-is, your app is vulnerable to SQL injection issues. (2) You could pre-read all of the rows to come up with the largest set of columns and create the table based on that. (3) When inserting items, you could compute `columns` based on the current item's keys?

Comment: (1)I'm not sure how to go about that but you've definitely given me something to look into.. (2) I had considered that but the number of rows it would have to read through I figured there was a better way I was missing. I probably will try it just to experiment. With this though I had concerns with having columns populate with mismatched columns in some cases. (3) Sort of what my concern with 2 was, is there a way to alter the table to insert new keys as needed and fill null for things that arent needed in an entry?

Comment: Iterating over 80,000 or so rows twice is peanuts for a computer larger than a toaster, so that's not an issue. You could, for sure, alter the table to add new columns later, but that's more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I got to an actual terminal, here's a refactoring of your code that runs nicely. I tried to pepper it with comments where necessary.

The idea is, anyway, that once we've downloaded a file from the API, we iterate over it to get a full list of columns, create a table based on that, and then use the same column list to generate rows (which have `None`s in them for columns that don't exist in that particular original row; and where data that can't be handled by SQLite by default is turned back into JSON for storage).

```
import json
import sqlite3

import requests

connection = sqlite3.connect("JSONTestDB.sqlite3")


def jsonify_complex_value(val):
    if isinstance(val, (dict, list)):
        return json.dumps(val)
    return val


def create_table_from_list(table_name, list_url):
    print(f"Downloading {table_name} from {list_url}")
    data_resp = requests.get(list_url)
    data_resp.raise_for_status()
    data = data_resp.json()
    assert isinstance(data, list)
    # Get all the columns
    all_columns = set()
    for row in data:
        all_columns.update(row.keys())

    # Some columns may be reserved words in SQLite, so we need to quote them
    # (but here's hoping there's nothing that needs more escaping)
    columns_for_sql = ",".join(f'"{col}"' for col in all_columns)
    qmarks_for_sql = ", ".join("?" * len(all_columns))

    print(f"{table_name} has {len(all_columns)} columns and {len(data)} rows")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Do everything here in a transaction for speed
    cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
    # Create the table
    create_table_sql = (
        f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ({columns_for_sql})"
    )
    cursor.execute(create_table_sql)

    # Create the insert statement
    insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({columns_for_sql}) VALUES ({qmarks_for_sql})"

    # Define a generator that will replace missing columns with None;
    # also, convert complex values to JSON.
    row_gen = (
        tuple(jsonify_complex_value(row.get(col)) for col in all_columns)
        for row in data
    )

    # Insert the data by running `insert_sql` in bulk
    cursor.executemany(insert_sql, row_gen)

    # Commit the transaction, we're done
    connection.commit()


def main():
    bulk_data_resp = requests.get("https://api.scryfall.com/bulk-data")
    bulk_data_resp.raise_for_status()
    for obj in bulk_data_resp.json()["data"]:
        table_name = obj["type"]
        url = obj["download_uri"]
        if table_name not in ("oracle_cards", "default_cards"):
            # Skip things we don't care about for this example
            print("Skipping", table_name)
            continue
        create_table_from_list(table_name, url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To verify that the data is there, and may contain gorgons:

```
$ sqlite3 JSONTestDB.sqlite3 'select name from oracle_cards order by random() limit 1;'
Vraska the Unseen
```

Comment: That is absolutely amazing, it worked perfectly and gave me so much more to research about Python. Thank you so much! 

After doing a bit more research, I think I have an understanding of it too. My only other question now (which is irrelevant as in the end I'll be querying the data rather than looking at the table anyway, more so for curiosity), since sets don't hold any order info, how would you establish an order to something like that, if it's even possible? If so, could you go in the order it's read, then insert new keys in that location?

Comment: I only use a `set` here while figuring out the columns; if I needed it to be in a given order for something else, I'd cast it to a list with `list(...)` or `sorted(...)`.

Comment: (Or if I needed to retain the order in which I'd seen the columns in the first place, I'd use both a list and a set, or maybe a dict to record a column name -> ordinal mapping.)

Comment: Fantastic, I'll start playing around with that. Thanks again